# Remove hidden input from form if the value has not been updated before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following form below.  When the user submits the form for search, if they haven't for example selected a region, I would like for any hidden input whose value is still nothing to be removed so it does't pass along that attribute to the url sting

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline" action="/test-results/">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="Price" id="price">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="Region" id="region">

          <div class="input-group">
            <select class="price">
              <option value="">Price</option>
              <option value="20">$20</option>
              <option value="500-1000">$500-1000</option>
              <option value="1500–2000">$1500–$2000</option>
              <option value="2000–2500">$2000–$2500</option>
              <option value="2500–3000">$2500–$3000</option>
              <option value="3000–3500">$3000–$3500</option>
              <option value="3500–4000">$3500–$4000</option>
              <option value="4000–4500">$4000–$4500</option>
              <option value="4500–5000">$4500–$5000</option>
              <option value="6500–7000">$6500–$7000</option>
              <option value="7000-9000">$7000-$9000</option>
              <option value="9500–10000">$9500–$10000</option>
              <option value="10000-30000">$10000-$30000</option>
              <option value="20000">$20000</option>
            </select>
            <select class="region">
              <option value="">Region</option>
              <option value="Place1">Place1</option>
              <option value="Place2">Place2</option>
              <option value="Place3">Place3</option>
              <option value="Place4">Place4</option>
              <option value="Place5">Place5</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="search-submit btn btn-default"><?php _e('Search Resorts', 'roots'); ?></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
```

thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need hidden fields at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the blank hidden elements like so:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    $(':hidden').filter(function() {
        return $.trim( this.value ) === '';
    })
    .remove();
});
```

Another alternative would be to have them initially **disabled** and when a value is set  they can be **enabled**; **disabled** fields are not included in the query string.